# Rails can't view associated model details in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a show view with this:

```
<%= @application.application_name %>
<%= @application.application_field %>
```

and it produces this:

```
Application name: New Employment App [#<ApplicationField id: 1, application_id: 1, applicant_id: nil, field_name: "Previous Job", field_type: "String", created_at: "2012-12-03 04:26:06", updated_at: "2012-12-03 04:26:06">, #<ApplicationField id: 2, application_id: 1, applicant_id: nil, field_name: "Previous Address", field_type: "String", created_at: "2012-12-03 04:26:06", updated_at: "2012-12-03 04:26:06">]
```

but if i do:

```
<%= @application.application_name %>
<%= @application.application_field.field_name %>
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `field_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff4ec822268>
```

Why am i getting this error?

Models are as follows

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    #has_many :applicants, :through => :application_field
    has_many :application_field
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :application_field, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :application_name, :application_field_attributes
end

class ApplicationField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :application
    has_many :application_fields_value
    #belongs_to :applicant
    attr_accessible :field_name, :field_type, :field_value, :application_field_values_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :application_fields_value, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

controller's show action:

```
# GET /applications/1
  # GET /applications/1.json
  def show
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @application }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Application has many ApplicationField. For example, one application has 3 
application_field. if you put application.application_field it will collect all the 3 application_field record and keep in an array. So if you put @application.application_field.field_name it will throw undefined method `field_name' for An ARRAY.

```
      try with <%= @application.application_field[0].field_name %>
```

Comment: Ahh yes thank you. A simple for loop will help me achieve this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
@application.application_field.first.field_name
```

...should get you the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

You could have written the model as follows:

`class Application < ActiveRecord::Base`
       `belongs_to :company`
      `has_many :application_fields`
     `accepts_nested_attributes_for :application_fields, :allow_destroy => true`
      `attr_accessible :application_name, :application_fields_attributes`
end`

Now the **Application** object will obviously have collection of **application_fields**.

Now you can show as follows in the show page:

`<%= @application.application_name %>`
`<%= @application.application_fields.map{|af| .field_name}.join(',') %>`